# How to combine the two scripts refreshing div into one?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I have two scripts refreshing div dynamic:
1) http://project-welcome.ugu.pl/test/ajax.js
2) http://project-welcome.ugu.pl/test/ajax2.js

I tried to combine it:

```
    // Customise those settings

    var seconds = 1;
    var divid = "timediv";
    var divid2 = "points";
    var url = "boo.php";
    var url2 = "boo2.php";

    // Refreshing the DIV

    function refreshdiv(){

    // The XMLHttpRequest object

    var xmlHttp;
    try{
    xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
    }
    catch (e){
    try{
    xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); // Internet Explorer
    }
    catch (e){
    try{
    xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch (e){
    alert("Your browser does not support AJAX.");
    return false;
    }
    }
    }

    // Timestamp for preventing IE caching the GET request

    fetch_unix_timestamp = function()
    {
    return parseInt(new Date().getTime().toString().substring(0, 10))
    }

    var timestamp = fetch_unix_timestamp();
    var nocacheurl = url+"?t="+timestamp;
    var nocacheurl2 = url2+"?t="+timestamp;
    // The code...

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
    document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
    document.getElementById(divid2).innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
    setTimeout('refreshdiv()',seconds*1000);
    }
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET",nocacheurl,true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
    xmlHttp.open("GET",nocacheurl2,true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
    }

    // Start the refreshing process

    var seconds;
    window.onload = function startrefresh(){
    setTimeout('refreshdiv()',seconds*1000);
    }
```

Source of index.html:

```
    <script src="ajax3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    refreshdiv();
    // --></script>
    Logs<div id="timediv"></div><br>
    Points<div id="points"></div><br>
```

It doesn't work because two div show the same (in this case points). 
How correct combine scripts?

P.s You can see it in file original.php
Login: testowyuser 
Pass: testtest 
then click "Strona Główna"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something goes last and overlaps the 1st.

It's Ok that you are complaining ;), look here

```
xmlHttp.open("GET",nocacheurl,true); // opening 1st URI
xmlHttp.send(null); // requresting. in the mean time we've got the response and our `onreadystatechange` function triggers

xmlHttp.open("GET",nocacheurl2,true); // opening 2nd URI
xmlHttp.send(null); // the same situation. received response, triggered function
```

You are using 1 `xmlHTTP` instance to request for both. and using it sequentially, but demanding it works simultaneously.

So when the function triggers (*doesn't matter 1st or 2nd time*) you suppose (*but not the script*) to have already 2 responses in **1** variable. Moreover, you want script guess what you actually want.

```
document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText; // getting response text from the current response (it can be 1st or 2nd response)
document.getElementById(divid2).innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText; // and again getting the current response text from the same instance (not the response you are expecting from the next request). so, you are repeating the same for the another <div>
```

Actually each time you have only one response text. And each time you are putting in your `<div's>` the same information (copy info over 2 `<div's>`) bec. there is no info about the next request yet.

And as the result in your script, I suppose, you have always last request copied over 2 `<div's>`.

**Try to** create 1 instance per "channel" (*1 instance of `xmlHTTP` for the 1st script to use and 1 for the second*) and set them different (separate) `onreadystatechange` function. This way you will not have overlap of data and will not be tangled.

**Far more elegant solution** (*less refactoring in JS*) is to distinguish responses. For e.g. if you are receiving XML, you can parse it for some **flag** that will tell you that this response is for `<div id=divid>` and another one is for another `<div>` or this request is first and this is the second etc.